# Should I import an exported constant that has multiple components in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have a constant in a file.

```js
//routes.ts
export const routes = [
  {path: "/", component: component1 },
  {path: "/two", component: component2 }
]
```

If I then import this const in any react component, does it import all the components too?
This wouldn't be a problem if I just use it for mapping the routes. But in some other components I need the array only for the `path` property. If I import the const in those components, will it add the component imports from `routes.ts` in those components as well? Should this be a performance issue?

Comment: It would be a reference, besides it's cached by the import anyway, so them components would be the same no matter how many times you import the file. Though you could always plop `export const routePaths = routes.map(v => v.path)` underneath and use that

Comment: It's _very, very_ normal to import values from other files and then export values that contain references to those imported values.